# How can I uncompress a *.7z file?

Tags: 7zip

How can I uncompress a *.7z file in Ubuntu and keep the directory structure?

Answer (score 533, accepted):

First install the `p7zip-full` package:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

With this, Nautilus should have an option to uncompress 7-Zip Files.

I also recommend `p7zip-rar` so it also includes support for RAR files.

This is assuming you want to do it via GUI with Nautilus. If not, after downloading the packages above do the following:

```
7z x PACKAGE.7z
```

that should eXtract the packages with full path.

Comment: I try to install 7zip-full using apt. I get this message: "Package p7zip-full is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source."

Comment: Note that if the compressed file is VERY large, it will be broken up into separate component files file.7z.001, file.7z.002, etc.  However, only the first file, file.7z.001, will show as an decompressable icon on the Nautilus desktop.  The others appear as data file icons.  Double-click this .7z.001 file to decompress ALL components in the package.  Also, apparently all of the .00x component files created during the compression have to be present, or else probably the .001 decompression will fail.

Comment: **Pay attention**: if you run `7z x my-archive.7z` all files **will be extracted to your home**! I had a huge archive now it will be a pain in the axe finding all files and moving them in the right place!

Comment: Hi @Sampgun pretty sure you were on your home folder when you ran that. Additionally there are 2 parameters, the "e" and "x", the main difference and why I recommend the "x" is because it preserves the folder structure inside the .7z file. So if you ended up with a huge amount of files in your home is because, you were in the home folder and the .7z file did not have a folder structure to begin with. Next time what you can do is create a folder, move the .7z over there and extract it inside of it to be safe. Good luck.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado yeah, I was in the home, now I see. I used the `x` option and the tree was respected, but the zip contained lots of files in its root. 
I did add the folder, in fact this was the command `7z x /var/www/html/archive.7z`. The `html` folder was empty, but still it extracted everything to the root, so...bummers!
I think there sould be some option as `-d` exists for `unzip`

Comment: @Sampgun I feel you buddy. Fully understand.

Comment: @posfan12 try `sudo apt-get update` before installing.

Answer (score 88):

There is also `dtrx` - which is immensely useful for un-archiving anything.

it stands for "**D**o **T**he **R**ight e**X**traction" - and will uncompress anything without any fuss.

simply:

```
sudo apt-get install dtrx
dtrx archive.tar.XX
```

Manpage: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dtrx.1.html

---

**UPDATE for Ubuntu 20.04 :**

According to their pypi page, dtrx is not *currently* available in the official repos. Thus, if you cannot install this via `apt`, then you can still use `pip3`:

```
pip3 install dtrx
```

If you don't already have pip3 installed, you can install it with

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: `it currently supports [...] InstallShield files.` very interesting.

Comment: You saved me, for some reason p7zip couldn't handle my files but dtrx worked like a charm.

Comment: Mandatory cliche link: https://xkcd.com/1168/

Comment: Seems perpect  (!), but on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS the result of `sudo apt install dtrx` is an **ERROR**, *"E: Unable to locate package dtrx"*.

Comment: You're right! will edit shortly

Answer (score 19):

Run following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full p7zip-rar
```

Or search through the ubuntu software center as 7zip and unrar and install the packages.

Answer (score 15):

For ubuntu 17.04, no need for the full package, `p7zip` is enough:

```
sudo apt install p7zip
```

Then, uncompress using the `-d` command:

```
p7zip -d something.7z
```

Comment: p7zip -d --keep something.7z or it will destroy your input file !!!!

Comment: This does not extract all files, due to features missing. in my case password protection. Thus this might be misleading.

Comment: Ah, so the default behavior is to delete the input. That is indeed very useful and polite. I wish all programs did this.

Answer (score 10):

First install the according package
`sudo apt install p7zip-full`

- use `x` flag to **extract** files with full path
- use `-o` flag to set **output directory**

`7z x <archive_name> -o{Directory}`

for example

`7z x file.7z -o/home/michael/Documents/NewFolder`

Notice that there is **no space** between `-o` and the **output directory**. If the file was encrypted, it will automatically ask for the password.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers did not work for me.

But this command worked fine:

```
7z e file.7z
```

Comment: You are right but, you need to use "x" to keep directory structures! Note that if you use the tag "e" f.eg 7z e Myfile.7z it will pull everything into your current working directory and overwritten of the existing files can be a permanent loss.

Answer (score 2):

here is unarchiver https://theunarchiver.com/command-line

```sh
sudo apt install unar
```

then

```
unar xxx.7z
```

that's it.

Comment: Why do you think `unrar` supports `7z` archives?

Comment: @Pilot6 it's `unar` not `unrar`

Comment: OK. So does it work with 7z?

Comment: @Pilot6 yes, https://packages.debian.org/buster/unar

Answer (score 0):

To extract all 7z archives into their own folder, using the archive name as the folder name:

```
7z x "*.7z" -o*
```

E.g., if one has the two files `a.7z` and `b.7z`, then folders `a` and `b` will be created and they'll contain the content of `a.7z` and `b.7z` (keeping the directory structure), respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In 2024 I think the easiest option is to use the Linux version of [7-zip](https://7-zip.org/download.html).

This provides an official tool which does not require any installation. The executable `7zzs` can be used out of the box and is portable. It also seems to have the same syntax as p7zip (at least for simple stuff). E.g. `7zzs x archive.7z` to extract. (Add it to your $PATH in order for 7zzs to work or use the full path e.g. `/directory/containing/the/executable/7zzs`)

---

Also possibly of interest: [Difference between several command-line tools provided for 7-Zip compression (like `7z`, `7zz`...)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465853/difference-between-several-command-line-tools-provided-for-7-zip-compression-li)