# how to extract tar.7z files from command line?

Tags: tar, compression, 7zip, decompression

Is there a way to extract files of tar.7z format using command line tools in Ubuntu?

Comment: yes it does @guntbert See the accepted answer "`7z x PACKAGE.7z` that should eXtract the packages with full path." How is that not command line?

Comment: Sorry, but the question is **not** a duplicate. It asks for handling **tar**.7z files. Neither the previous question nor its answers cover this matter. Since the answers don't address this question fully, it was legitimate to pose the question here.

Comment: Yes I also agree, the point of the question is the extraction of the files with a tar.7z format.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Please give some time before marking any post as duplicate. Since you marked it first, all copied your action. This question is for extracting ***.tar.7z** not ***.7z** !! I guess you know the difference.. :)

Comment: @SauravKumar they are exactly the same.Linux does not care about suffixes and an extraction is based on the 1st bytes of the file. It is an identical question. And I trust stephen, andrea, guntbert enough to PM me in chat when I mess up (I have lots of examples of that :D )

Comment: `man tar` mentions `--format=v7`, but unfortunately that's only for creating such files, not for extracting from them.

Comment: As a comment since new answers aren't allowed here: In 2024 I think it makes sense to use the official Linux version of 7-zip. See my answers here:https://askubuntu.com/a/1506737/800252.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Yes - the package `p7zip` / `p7zip-full` provides a command-line application to zip/unzip 7z files. The command is simply `7z`.

You can **combine a `7z` / `tar` call** using a pipe:

```
7z x -so yourfile.tar.7z | tar xf - -C target_dir
```

where target_dir is a already-existing directory.

Comment: Who ever publishes tar.7z (lzma compression) files should learn about tar.xz/txz (lzma2), since this compression if available for `tar` via `J` parameter (like `tar -cJf`; not to be confused: capital J is for xz, small j is for bzip2) when `xz-tools` package is installed. It's also the default format on kernel.org.

Comment: People may wish to use 7zip for the strong encryption and multi-volume support.

Comment: I found the answer to my question of why people combine tarballs with 7z. Even though 7z can store trees of files, it apparently does not preserve Unix permissions and metadata, so tarball can be used to preserve that while using 7z. But then, I agree with @LiveWireBT, just use xz, gzip, or bzip2.

Comment: 7z appears to be better for lots of smaller files.

Comment: The cmd. line proposed here is not working
`$  sudo 7z x -so Prime95/p95v294b7.linux64 | tar xf - -C /usr/local/bin/`
gave me 
`Error: can't decompress folder
tar: This does not look like a tar archive`
The working cmd. is
`$ sudo 7z x Prime95/p95v294b7.linux64.7z -o/usr/local/bin/`
using the option from the bash cmd. 7z `http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/7z.1.html`

Comment: @Antonio: The question (an thus, my answer) concerned **tar**.7z files, not simple .7z archives. If your file isn't a compressed tar archive, of course my cmd line example will fail, since the tar command doesn't find a tar archive to expand.

Comment: As a comment since new answers aren't allowed here: In 2024 I think it makes sense to use the official Linux version of 7-zip. See my answers here:https://askubuntu.com/a/1506737/800252.

Answer (score 78):

- Install p7zip-full if not already installed:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
  ```
- execute this command to extract .tar.7z file(go to directory where is your file, if `myfile.tar.7z` is your file name):

  ```
  7za x myfile.tar.7z
  tar -xvf myfile.tar
  ```
- That's it. Actually first command extracts in .tar file then next command extracts it completely.

Answer (score 44):

Make sure that 7zip is installed, if not, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip
```

To install the command line utility do:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Once done you can do the following to extract:

```
7z e <file_name>.tar.7z
```

To extract with full paths:

```
7z x <file_name>.tar.7z
```

To specify a path to extract to:

```
7z x <file_name>.tar.7z -opath
```

7z does not allow spaces between `-o` and path.

Comment: `7z x ghost.7z -o/home/node/` to extract to /home/node/ghost

Comment: To open a password protected file you can provide -p<your password> as argument.

Comment: @Mitch, "To specify a path to extract to:", the path has to be continued with "-o" like "-o/mypath"

Comment: Thanks @DineshKumarP, I was not getting put the destination path until sees his explanation saying that "-o" must be along the way "-o/path".