# How to know actual size of a compressed file in ubuntu using command?

Tags: command-line, tar, compression

I have a wikipedia dump file of around 15GB which extension is .tar.7z. In it has another .tar file. The main content has in .tar file.

**How to get the original size of all files those have in the tar file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.tar` in `.tar.7z`? That's strange. If it was just two levels (`.7z` and `.tar`) you could do:

```
tar tvf foo.tar.7z
```

For example,

```
$ tar tvf certbot.tar.xz
drwxr-xr-x muru/muru   0 2016-07-06 19:30 certbot/
-rw-r--r-- muru/muru 362 2016-07-06 19:30 certbot/CHANGES.rst
drwxr-xr-x muru/muru   0 2016-07-06 19:30 certbot/letsencrypt-nginx/
drwxr-xr-x muru/muru   0 2016-07-06 19:30 certbot/letsencrypt-nginx/letsencrypt_nginx/
-rw-r--r-- muru/muru 119 2016-07-06 19:30 certbot/letsencrypt-nginx/letsencrypt_nginx/__init__.py
-rw-r--r-- muru/muru 11984 2016-07-06 19:30 certbot/letsencrypt-nginx/LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r-- muru/muru   118 2016-07-06 19:30 certbot/letsencrypt-nginx/README.rst
-rw-r--r-- muru/muru  1638 2016-07-06 19:30 certbot/letsencrypt-nginx/setup.py
-rw-r--r-- muru/muru    39 2016-07-06 19:30 certbot/letsencrypt-nginx/MANIFEST.in
-rw-r--r-- muru/muru   604 2016-07-06 19:30 certbot/CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r-- muru/muru   494 2016-07-06 19:30 certbot/readthedocs.org.requirements.txt
...
```

As you can see, the file sizes are listed in the third column.

Comment: i am getting this =>
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Archive contains ‘}l\375\362(\232m\v\377\262\237l’ where numeric off_t value expected
tar: Archive contains ‘\301<\236f\351\351\366\024\023\244\312\343’ where numeric off_t value expected

Comment: Add the output of `file filename` to your question

Comment: wikipedia-en-html.tar.7z....In it has this file ==>wikipedia-en-html.tar...

Comment: @SudipDas then use this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/341636/158442 in combination with mine