# How to open a .7z file through terminal

Tags: command-line

So I encrypted one of my directories using 7z. with a password. When I open it using the GUI it says Password required... what I want is to do this through terminal. First thing I tried was xdg-open but that brought me back to the GUI. When I tried to research this all it gave me was how to unzip the file. Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/219392/how-can-i-uncompress-a-7z-file

Answer (score 1):

You only need the -p parameter for that. So if my password is 123 the line would read

```
7z x -p123 file.7z
```

Comment: Gives me the error: Incorrect command line

Comment: Did you even install the p7zip package?

Comment: @Peyto, this is the solution!

Comment: I have it installed and It doesn't work; still gives the error above

Comment: @Peyto Please upload an image or the full line you are putting on the terminal and what version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: This answer is correct. I installed `p7zip-full` on Ubuntu 20.04. If you don't provide `-p` option. It will prompt for the password.